# SEGV thrown with std::unordered_map using boost interprocess allocators after shrink_to_fit()

Tags: c++11, boost, unordered-map, allocator, boost-interprocess

I'm using boost-1.68 and gcc-7.3.0 with `-std=c++11`. The following code as written throws a SIGSEGV for me.

The problem is caused by the combination of using `std::unordered_map` along with the boost interprocess `shrink_to_fit()` method. Changing the `shared::unordered_map` type from `std::unordered_map` to `boost::unordered_map` and/or commenting out the call to `shrink_to_fit()` will fix the code.

I ultimately don't intend to use `std::unordered_map`, but the fact that this minimal example is failing makes me concerned that I'm not properly setting up and/or not properly using the allocators.

EDIT: Should have mentioned that using `shrink_to_fit()` is necessary for my purposes.

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <scoped_allocator>

#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

namespace shared {
    using segment_type = boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file;
    using segment_manager = segment_type::segment_manager;

    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = boost::interprocess::allocator<T, segment_manager>;

    template <typename T>
    using ScopedAlloc = std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<Alloc<T>>;

    using string = boost::interprocess::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    template <typename Key, typename Val, typename KHash = boost::hash<Key>, typename KEqual = std::equal_to<Key>>
    using unordered_map =
        std::unordered_map<Key, Val, KHash, KEqual, ScopedAlloc<std::pair<const Key, Val>>>;
}

struct MyStruct {
    shared::unordered_map<shared::string, int> some_map;

    MyStruct (shared::segment_manager *smgr)
    : some_map{smgr}
    { }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const MyStruct& m) {
        os << "{";
        for (auto& e : m.some_map) {
            os << "{\"" << e.first << "\"," << e.second << "}";
        }
        os << "}";
        return os;
    }
};

int main () {
    const char *filename = "content.bin";
    std::remove(filename);

    {
        shared::segment_type segment(boost::interprocess::create_only, filename, (1<<20));
        MyStruct *o1 = segment.construct<MyStruct>("MyStruct01")(segment.get_segment_manager());
        o1->some_map.emplace("entry_1", 1);
        o1->some_map.emplace("entry_2", 2);
        o1->some_map.emplace("entry_3", 3);
        cout << "constructed MyStruct01: " << *o1 << endl;
    }

    shared::segment_type::shrink_to_fit(filename);

    {
        shared::segment_type segment(boost::interprocess::open_read_only, filename);
        MyStruct *o1 = (segment.find<MyStruct>("MyStruct01")).first;
        cout << "      found MyStruct01: " << *o1 << endl;
    }

    cout << "completed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  I put some instrumentation in the code to do some sleuthing.  I won't include it here, but I used `std::system` to run `ls` against the the mapped file, and to run `pmap` against the process at different points.  In particular, I wanted to see where the mapped file is in the process address space.  I also dumped out the addresses of the entries returned by the range-for loop in the `operator<<` method to see where they were in the address space.

When using `std::unordered_map`, I got the following information:

Before `shrink_to_fit()`:

- Mapped file size: 1048576
- File mapping address range: 0x7f4f912d5000 - 0x7f4f913d5000
- Addresses of map entries: 0x7f4f912d5238, 0x7f4f912d5188, 0x7f4f912d51f8

So, everything looks good there.

After `shrink_to_fit()`:

- Mapped file size: 688
- File mapping address range: 0x7f4f919c6000 - 0x7f4f919c62b0
- Addresses of map entry: 0x7f4f912d5238 (SEGV)

That map entry is completely outside the file mapping address range.

Compare to using `boost::unordered_map`:

Before `shrink_to_fit()`:

- Mapped file size: 1048576
- File mapping address range: 0x7fe06957f000 - 0x7fe06967f000
- Addresses of map entries: 0x7fe06957f2d0, 0x7fe06957f290, 0x7fe06957f180

All good.

After `shrink_to_fit()`:

- Mapped file size: 784
- File mapping address range: 0x7fe069c70000 - 0x7fe069c70310
- Addresses of map entries: 0x7fe069c702d0, 0x7fe069c70290, 0x7fe069c70180

All within the mapped address space.

Switching back to `std::unordered_map`, if I omit the call to `shrink_to_fit()`, then the file is mapped back into the same address space, and everything "works".  If had been mapped into a different address space, then it probably would have crashed similarly.

If I had to guess, I would say that `std::unordered_map` is using regular pointers, rather than the boost interprocess `offset_ptr` that it should be using.

Comment: What does the debugger say about the memory around the crash and the type of access?  Often looking at registers and memory locations of the crash will tell a lot of information, more than crystal balling from code.

Comment: This could be a bug in the libstdc++ implementation of unordered_map. libc++ works as expected. Perhaps libstdc++ uses a raw pointer somewhere an allocator::pointer should be used.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - see big edit after code listing.  Looks as though std::unordered_map is accessing addresses outside the file mapping.

Comment: @n.m. - I think that's exactly it. see big edit after code listing. Looks as though std::unordered_map is accessing addresses outside the file mapping.

Comment: @smcdow  Maybe you can find out where exactly this raw pointer sits and file a bug to libstdc++.